# jquery all divs opening and closing when toggle is clicked

Tags: jquery

When i click in a link all the divs with the relevant classes open and close.

How do I apply the .this function to the jquery?
i
This is the code I have, I would only like to activate the the one that is clicked

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
    //On Click
    $('.collapseLink').click(function(){
        $('.revealBoxContents').stop(true, true).slideToggle('slow');
    });
});
```

here is the html unfortunatly I am not allowed to change this markup

```
<div class="revealBox revealBoxClosed">
            <div class="revealBoxTop">
                <h3>About You</h3>
           <a class="collapseLink" title="" href="javascript:void(0);"><span class="dottedBot">Hide information</span><img width="16" height="16" class="detailListActions" alt="-" src="Resources/Images/BBG/main/minus.gif"></a>              </div>
            <!-- /revealBoxTop -->
         <div class="revealBoxContents" style="display: block;">
           <div class="detailListHead pad10">
              <span class="floatLeft">Details about you </span>
             <span class="floatRight">Edit</span>
             <div class="clearBoth"></div>
           </div>

            <ul class="revealDetailsList">
              <li class="table shadedList ">
             <div class="tableRow">
              <span class="detailCell detailLabel">Your Name:</span>
              <p class="detailResult">Mr John Smith</p>
             <a class="detailCell detailListActions" title="" href="javascript:void(0);"><img width="16" height="16" alt="?" src="Resources/Images/BBG/main/iconq.gif"></a>

             </div><!-- /tableRow -->
                          </li>
              <li class="table">
             <div class="tableRow">
              <span class="detailCell detailLabel">Gender:</span>
              <p class="detailResult">Male</p>
             <a class="detailCell detailListActions" title="" href="javascript:void(0);"><img width="16" height="16" alt="?" src="Resources/Images/BBG/main/iconq.gif"></a>
             <a class="detailCell detailListActions" title="" href="javascript:void(0);"><img width="16" height="16" class="marginRight10" alt="Edit" src="Resources/Images/BBG/eqs/edit.gif"></a>
             </div><!-- /tableRow -->
                            </li>
              <li class="table shadedList ">
             <div class="tableRow">
              <span class="detailCell detailLabel">Date of Birth:</span>
              <p class="detailResult">11/11/1977</p>
             <a class="detailCell detailListActions" title="" href="javascript:void(0);"><img width="16" height="16" alt="?" src="Resources/Images/BBG/main/iconq.gif"></a>
             <a class="detailCell detailListActions" title="" href="javascript:void(0);"><img width="16" height="16" class="marginRight10" alt="Edit" src="Resources/Images/BBG/eqs/edit.gif"></a>
             </div><!-- /tableRow -->
                            </li>
              <li class="table">
             <div class="tableRow">
              <span class="detailCell detailLabel">Postal Address:</span>
              <p class="detailResult">1 Buchanan Street, Derby, Derbyshire, DE1 3BZ 1 Buchanan Street, Derby, Derbyshire, DE1 3BZ</p>
             <a class="detailCell detailListActions" title="" href="javascript:void(0);"><img width="16" height="16" alt="?" src="Resources/Images/BBG/main/iconq.gif"></a>
             <a class="detailCell detailListActions" title="" href="javascript:void(0);"><img width="16" height="16" class="marginRight10" alt="Edit" src="Resources/Images/BBG/eqs/edit.gif"></a>
             </div><!-- /tableRow -->
                            </li>
              <li class="table shadedList ">
             <div class="tableRow">
              <span class="detailCell detailLabel">Relationship Status:</span>
              <p class="detailResult">Married</p>
             <a class="detailCell detailListActions" title="" href="javascript:void(0);"><img width="16" height="16" alt="?" src="Resources/Images/BBG/main/iconq.gif"></a>
             <a class="detailCell detailListActions" title="" href="javascript:void(0);"><img width="16" height="16" class="marginRight10" alt="Edit" src="Resources/Images/BBG/eqs/edit.gif"></a>
             </div><!-- /tableRow -->
                            </li>
              <li class="table">
             <div class="tableRow">
              <span class="detailCell detailLabel">Daytime/Mobile Telephone:</span>
              <p class="detailResult">01977 123245</p>
             <a class="detailCell detailListActions" title="" href="javascript:void(0);"><img width="16" height="16" alt="?" src="Resources/Images/BBG/main/iconq.gif"></a>
             <a class="detailCell detailListActions" title="" href="javascript:void(0);"><img width="16" height="16" class="marginRight10" alt="Edit" src="Resources/Images/BBG/eqs/edit.gif"></a>
             </div><!-- /tableRow -->
                            </li>
              <li class="table shadedList ">
             <div class="tableRow">
              <span class="detailCell detailLabel">Email Address:</span>
              <p class="detailResult">john.smith@email.com</p>
             <a class="detailCell detailListActions" title="" href="javascript:void(0);"><img width="16" height="16" alt="?" src="Resources/Images/BBG/main/iconq.gif"></a>
             <a class="detailCell detailListActions" title="" href="javascript:void(0);"><img width="16" height="16" class="marginRight10" alt="Edit" src="Resources/Images/BBG/eqs/edit.gif"></a>
             </div><!-- /tableRow -->
                            </li>
              <li class="table">
             <div class="tableRow">
              <span class="detailCell detailLabel">Date you wish your insurance to start:</span>
              <p class="detailResult">2/03/2011</p>
             <a class="detailCell detailListActions" title="" href="javascript:void(0);"><img width="16" height="16" alt="?" src="Resources/Images/BBG/main/iconq.gif"></a>
             <a class="detailCell detailListActions" title="" href="javascript:void(0);"><img width="16" height="16" class="marginRight10" alt="Edit" src="Resources/Images/BBG/eqs/edit.gif"></a>
             </div><!-- /tableRow -->
                            </li>
              <li class="table shadedList ">
             <div class="tableRow">
              <span class="detailCell detailLabel">Employment Status:</span>
              <p class="detailResult">Employed</p>
             <a class="detailCell detailListActions" title="" href="javascript:void(0);"><img width="16" height="16" alt="?" src="Resources/Images/BBG/main/iconq.gif"></a>
             <a class="detailCell detailListActions" title="" href="javascript:void(0);"><img width="16" height="16" class="marginRight10" alt="Edit" src="Resources/Images/BBG/eqs/edit.gif"></a>
             </div><!-- /tableRow -->
                            </li>
              <li class="table">
             <div class="tableRow">
              <span class="detailCell detailLabel">Your Occupation:</span>
              <p class="detailResult">Marketing Manager</p>
             <a class="detailCell detailListActions" title="" href="javascript:void(0);"><img width="16" height="16" alt="?" src="Resources/Images/BBG/main/iconq.gif"></a>
             <a class="detailCell detailListActions" title="" href="javascript:void(0);"><img width="16" height="16" class="marginRight10" alt="Edit" src="Resources/Images/BBG/eqs/edit.gif"></a>
             </div><!-- /tableRow -->
                            </li>
              <li class="table shadedList ">
             <div class="tableRow">
              <span class="detailCell detailLabel">Business Type:</span>
              <p class="detailResult">Insurance Broker</p>
             <a class="detailCell detailListActions" title="" href="javascript:void(0);"><img width="16" height="16" alt="?" src="Resources/Images/BBG/main/iconq.gif"></a>
             <a class="detailCell detailListActions" title="" href="javascript:void(0);"><img width="16" height="16" class="marginRight10" alt="Edit" src="Resources/Images/BBG/eqs/edit.gif"></a>
             </div><!-- /tableRow -->
                            </li>
              <li class="table lastLi">
             <div class="tableRow">
              <span class="detailCell detailLabel">Joint Policy Holder:</span>
              <p class="detailResult">Mrs Jane Smith</p>
             <a class="detailCell detailListActions" title="" href="javascript:void(0);"><img width="16" height="16" alt="?" src="Resources/Images/BBG/main/iconq.gif"></a>
             <a class="detailCell detailListActions" title="" href="javascript:void(0);"><img width="16" height="16" class="marginRight10" alt="Edit" src="Resources/Images/BBG/eqs/edit.gif"></a>
             </div><!-- /tableRow -->
                            </li>

           </ul><!-- /revealDetails -->
                <div class="relative">
                <a class="collapseLink floatRight" title="" href="javascript:void(0);"><span class="dottedBot">Hide information</span><img width="16" height="16" class="detailListActions" alt="?" src="Resources/Images/BBG/main/minus.gif"></a>               
            </div>
         </div><!-- /revealBoxContents -->
       </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You wrap `this` with the jQuery `$` operator:

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
    //On Click
    $('.collapseLink').click(function(){
        $(this).parent().next(".revealBoxContents").stop(true, true).slideToggle('slow');
    });
});
```

As one commenter mentioned, this will only work if it is within the link. `.closest()` may help you in place of `find()` if it is outside.

If you post your HTML we might be able to help more.

Comment: this won't work. it will toggle the collapseLink and not the `.revealBoxContents`

Comment: @Fender - Added a `find()` which should fix this.

Comment: that only works if the .revealBoxContents is within the link, otherwise, you'll need some way of associating each content box with the link, using a data- (data dash) attribute

Comment: Post some of your HTML. DOM elements are acceed through traversal functions. Its important to know what you want accessed and where it is in relation to everything else.

Comment: sure heres the html, I am not allowed to  change it

Comment: Where? Edit our original question and then code-format it using the `{}` button.

Comment: just added the html to the original question, check above

Comment: I've edited the code. I'm assuming you want the `.revealboxcontetents` div below the anchor to activated. `$(this).parent().next(".revealBoxContents")......`

Answer (score 3):

this works:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //On Click
    $('.collapseLink').click(function() {
        $(this).parent().next('div.revealBoxContents').stop(true, true).slideToggle();
    });
});
```

look at this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/RVjbY/1/

Comment: Hi there the link is in a div above the element that wants to beopen and closed but they are both in a parent div

Answer (score 1):

If the link is inside the div you want to toggle, try this

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
    //On Click
    $('.collapseLink').click(function(){
        $(this).parents('.revealBoxContents').stop(true, true).slideToggle('slow');
    });
});
```

Basically, idea is to choose the toggling div, relative to clicked link (usually using `this`);

Happy Coding.

Comment: the link is above the div that wants to be toggled